# How to create images for web in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Horrible thing about inkscape is, that it does everything on a A4 page layout. Oh, yes, you can somehow, after finding the secret button in secret menu, access a popup that allows to change layout size.

Still, offseting the object to [0,0] coordinates results in it being here:
[image]

[image: Screenshot of the svg image opened in browser]

Making UI elements does not seem possible this way.

So, to make a SVG image that is supposed to be displayed within `<img>`, what do I do?

Exporting to PNG works - but if I wanted PNG, I can use MSPaint.

Comment: no need for secret button or secret menu :) - it's on the file menu, document properties option...

Answer (score 1):

Use the menu **File** - **Document Properties** so you can use the size you want for the page.

If creating a new page, use **File** - **New** and select the size you want in the drop down instead of using the default one.

A4 page layout is only the default, but you can use others and custom sizes also.

You can fit the document to the current drawing for example with: **Resize Page to Content** option in Document properties.